# Python If And statement throws KeyError 9 in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I'm trying to filter a df column and rename certain rows depending on next/previous row value.

[image]

This code (without AND though) worked for me for other sorting in the same df:

```
for row in df.index:
    if df['col1'][row] == 'b' and df['col1'][row+1] =='name':
        df['col1'][row +1] = 'name1' 
        df['col1'][row +2] = 'name2'
```

Here it throws KeyError 9 and I assume it's because of AND condition in row+1. Is there any way to workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because the index is out of range.

When in the for loop run with "row = 8", the last row for dataframe, therefore "df['col']['row+1'] is invalid.

Because row+1 = 9 is out of range. "KeyError 9" means cannot find the index "9" in your dataframe.

Comment: the dataframe is [1972 rows x 3 columns]

Comment: i think it still return the error when the loop go to the last row, can you try with "for row in range(0,5):" to check that if it is the problem.

Comment: the exact same loop works properly on the same df without And condition

Comment: yes, 'row+1' is appear in the second term of the 'and condition'

Comment: @Irrats If this still doesn't resolve the problem for you, please edit the question to add in any missing information (for example, you have shown some sample data, but you haven't show us what df.index looks like, or mentioned the dimensions of the data in the question. You should try to reduce the problem down to a [mre] and post the minimal data and code (ideally as data, not as a picture of data) that can reproduce your problem.